# Zoom In/Out Interferes with Canvas Drawing Location

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working with some classmates to make a word search game.  It is pretty much done, but the only problem that we are facing is when the user decides to zoom in or out.  When the user clicks and drags their cursor within the canvas, a red line highlights the letters under the cursor.  After zooming, the highlighting appears somewhere other than under the mouse.

At first, we thought the problem was caused by window scrolling because the canvases were bigger than the screen, so we made them

You can recreate the problem by going [here](http://cs.neiu.edu/~mtdiff/easy.html), zooming in, scrolling down a little bit, and trying to highlight a string of letters.

*Please only include suggestions with Javascript: no JQuery, additional libraries, any other languages.*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas,//canvas html tag
        wordsCanvas,//displays words
        wContext,//wordsCanvas context
        context,//to edit canvas items 
        words = ["KING","HOMEWORK","BASEBALL","SIDEWALK","CUPCAKE","WHITEHOUSE","ISLAND","SOCCER","INDEPENDENCE","LOVE","CALCULUS","BEACH","SUMMER","PET","MICHIGAN","CANDY","WORLD","SIX","SNOW","SWEET"],//array of the words users must find
        found = new Array(),
        w,//width
        h,//height
        w1,//width of each letter (board 6 letters wide right now)
        h1,//height of each letter (board 6 letters tall right now)
        draw = false,//tells when the game should highlight a letter
        letterPoints = new Array(),//holds the coordinates of each letter
        lines = new Array(),//holds the coordinates of each line for a correct word highlighted
        startLP = null,//holds the Letter object (letter, x, y) for the start of the line
        endLP = null;//holds the Letter object (letter, x, y) for the end of the line

        function init(){//initializes the canvas, context,w,h variables
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight*600/630;
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth*900/1380;
            w=canvas.width;
            h=canvas.height;
            w1 = w/20;
            h1 = h/20;
            context.font = h1+"px Courier";
            context.textAlign = "left";
            context.textBaseline = "top";

            wordsCanvas = document.getElementById("wordsCanvas");
            wordsCanvas.height = window.innerHeight*600/630;
            wordsCanvas.width = window.innerWidth*400/1380;
            wContext = wordsCanvas.getContext("2d");
            wContext.font = h1+"px Georgia";
            wContext.textAlign = "left";
            wContext.textBaseline = "top";

            background();
            fillWords(-1);

            //add event listeners for mouse actions
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
                setLine("press",event);
            });
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
                setLine("release",event);
            });
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
                setLine("drag",event);
            });
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
                setLine("out",event);
            });
        }

        function fillWords(greenIndex){//displays words to search for
            wContext.clearRect(0,0,300,h);
            var index = 0;
            if(greenIndex != -1)
            {
                found[found.length] = words.splice(greenIndex,1);
            }

            for(var i=0; i<h; i+=h1)
            {
                if(index<words.length)
                {
                    wContext.fillStyle = "red";
                    wContext.fillText(words[index],10,i);
                }
                else
                {
                    wContext.fillStyle = "green";
                    wContext.fillText(found[found.length-((h/h1)-index)],10,i);
                }
                index++;
            }

            wContext.fillStyle = "black";
        }

        function background(){//sets the background to the letters and then draws the lines that lay on correctly highlighted words words
            var letterCount = 0;//counts # of letters on the board
            //one string that represents all letters on the board
            var backLets = "harinavesenanotheasp"+
                           "oobalremmusicwonsdpa"+
                           "momvtcalclsxvaiybaev"+
                           "swttysumvkingbddmrzd"+
                           "ahaeuyacemjtavpniche"+
                           "nivpnagihcimbseaceoy"+
                           "tthesteatkijeodchqmj"+
                           "ueesnodbsggmaccutsea"+
                           "mhmikalviabahceraqwm"+
                           "motislandbtcvetiwmoi"+
                           "eurwtenkeeeterntanra"+
                           "tsoolotewheewhthsekl"+
                           "sewroxvrarwdbaseball"+
                           "nehtvxjglmsadalkazqt"+
                           "odceetenkenstcvepcap"+
                           "ttaabvdlcupcakepeaxm"+
                           "rieqindependenceplia"+
                           "afbacucakehowrkdkisf"+
                           "chldlrowbrqmmuscqflg"+
                           "amerivegdsuluclacoev";

            context.fillStyle = "black";
            for(var y=0; y<h; y+=h1)//goes through the board and draws each letter, then stores their coordinates in the letterPoints array
            {
                for(var x=0; x<w; x+=w1)
                {
                    r = y/h1 + 1;//tells the row that the letter is in
                    c = x/w1 + 1;//tells the column that the letter is in
                    temp = new Letter(backLets.charAt(letterCount),x,y,r,c);
                    context.fillText(temp.letter.toUpperCase(),temp.x,temp.y);
                    if(letterPoints.length<400)
                        letterPoints[letterPoints.length] = temp;
                    letterCount++;
                }
            }

            /*go through lines array holding coordinates for lines that lay on correct words*/
            for(var z=0; z<lines.length; z++)
            {
                //this if structure allows the words matching the list to be highlighted in different colors so adjacent words will not be highlighted into blocks 
                context.fillStyle = "lime";

                var coords = lines[z];//elements of lines array are not empty but the drawLine isn't processing them
                drawLine(coords[0],coords[1]);
            }
        }

        function setLine(action, e){//sets the coordinates for the lines to be drawn
            if(action == "press")
            {
                startLP = findNearestLP(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);//gets nearest coordenate to a click and returns a letter object with that info
                if(startLP != null)
                {
                    draw = true;
                }
            }
            if(action == "drag")
            {
                //updates the last coordinates that the dragged mouse is on and draws a line to that point from the start
                if(draw)
                {
                    context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
                    background();
                    endLP = findNearestLP(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);

                    context.fillStyle = "red";
                    drawLine(startLP, endLP);
                }
            }
            if(action == "release"  || (action == "out" && draw))
            {
                draw = false;
                /*If a correct word is highlighted, store the start and end coordinates
                else clear*/
                endLP = findNearestLP(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
                //Get the letters that are highlighted by the line
                if(endLP != null)
                {
                    var word = getWord();//returns the word that was made from the start to end point by adding the characters that were highlighted
                    if(word != null && matchWords(word)/*This string will be replaced by a word from the list of word search targets*/)
                    {
                        lines[lines.length] = [startLP,endLP];
                    }
                }
                context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);//clears the board of any drawn lines
                background();//if the line highlighted a word from the list, this method should redraw that line

                if(words.length == 0)
                    alert("Congratulations! You win!");

            }
        }

        //searches through the words array to see if the highlighted word is there
        function matchWords(target){
            if(words.indexOf(target.toUpperCase()) != -1)
            {
                fillWords(words.indexOf(target.toUpperCase()));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //uses coordinates from setLine() to draw the lines
        function drawLine(start, end){
            context.globalAlpha = 0.6;//sets transparency of lines

            /*
                Check up,down,left,right,diagonals
                See if start and end can make a valid line
                If yes, find the letters from start to end and store it as a word
            */

            if(start.x == end.x && end.y>start.y)//checking down
            {
                context.fillRect(start.x,start.y,w1,(end.y+h1)-start.y);
            }
            else if(start.x == end.x && end.y<start.y)//checking up
            {
                context.fillRect(end.x,end.y,w1,(start.y+h1)-end.y);
            }
            else if(start.y == end.y && end.x>start.x)//checking left to right
            {
                context.fillRect(start.x,start.y,(end.x+w1)-start.x,h1);
            }
            else if(start.y == end.y && end.x<start.x)//checking right to left
            {
                context.fillRect(end.x,end.y,(start.x+w1)-end.x,h1);
            }
            else if(start.y > end.y && start.x < end.x && ((start.r-end.r)/(end.c-start.c))==1)//checking left to right diagonal (down to up)
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((start.x<=temp.x && end.x>=temp.x && start.y>=temp.y && end.y<=temp.y) && ((start.y-temp.y==0 && temp.x-start.x==0) || ((start.r-temp.r)/(temp.c-start.c))==1))//((start.r-temp.r)/(temp.c-start.c))==1  means if the slope of between two points is 1
                    {   
                        context.fillRect(temp.x,temp.y,w1,h1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(start.y < end.y && start.x < end.x && ((end.r-start.r)/(end.c-start.c))==1)//checking left to right diagonal (top to bottom)
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((start.x<=temp.x && end.x>=temp.x && start.y<=temp.y && end.y>=temp.y) && ((start.y-temp.y==0 && temp.x-start.x==0) || ((temp.r-start.r)/(temp.c-start.c))==1))//((temp.r-start.r)/(temp.c-start.c))==1  means if the slope of between two points is 1
                    {   
                        context.fillRect(temp.x,temp.y,w1,h1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(start.y > end.y && start.x > end.x && ((start.r-end.r)/(start.c-end.c))==1)//checking right to left diagonal (down to up)
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((start.x>=temp.x && end.x<=temp.x && start.y>=temp.y && end.y<=temp.y) && ((start.y-temp.y==0 && start.x-temp.x==0) || ((start.r-temp.r)/(start.c-temp.c))==1))
                    {   
                        context.fillRect(temp.x,temp.y,w1,h1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(start.y < end.y && start.x > end.x && ((end.r-start.r)/(start.c-end.c))==1)//checking right diagonal (top to bottom)
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((start.x>=temp.x && end.x<=temp.x && start.y<=temp.y && end.y>=temp.y) && ((start.y-temp.y==0 && start.x-temp.x==0) || ((temp.r-start.r)/(start.c-temp.c))==1))
                    {   
                        context.fillRect(temp.x,temp.y,w1,h1);
                    }
                }
            }
            context.globalAlpha = 1.0;//sets transparency back to 1
        }           

        function findNearestLP(clickX,clickY){//finds the nearest letter coordinate from the user's click
            for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
            {
                var lp = letterPoints[z];
                if((clickX<=lp.x+w1 && clickX>=lp.x) && (clickY<=lp.y+h1 && clickY>=lp.y))
                {   
                    return letterPoints[z];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function getWord()
        {
            var result = "";
            /*
                Check up,down,left,right,diagonals
                See if startLP and endLP can make a valid line
                If yes, find the letters from start to end and store it as a word
            */

            if(startLP.x == endLP.x && endLP.y>startLP.y)//checking down
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if(temp.x == startLP.x && temp.y>=startLP.y && temp.y<=endLP.y)
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.x == endLP.x && endLP.y<startLP.y)//checking up
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if(temp.x == startLP.x && temp.y<=startLP.y && temp.y>=endLP.y)
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y == endLP.y && endLP.x>startLP.x)//checking left to right
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if(temp.y == startLP.y && temp.x>=startLP.x && temp.x<=endLP.x)
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y == endLP.y && endLP.x<startLP.x)//checking right to left
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if(temp.y == startLP.y && temp.x<=startLP.x && temp.x>=endLP.x)
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y > endLP.y && startLP.x < endLP.x && ((startLP.r-endLP.r)/(endLP.c-startLP.c))==1)//checking left to right diagonal (down to up)
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((startLP.x<=temp.x && endLP.x>=temp.x && startLP.y>=temp.y && endLP.y<=temp.y) && ((startLP.y-temp.y==0 && temp.x-startLP.x==0) || ((startLP.r-temp.r)/(temp.c-startLP.c))==1))
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y < endLP.y && startLP.x < endLP.x && ((endLP.r-startLP.r)/(endLP.c-startLP.c))==1)//checking left to right diagonal (top to bottom)
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((startLP.x<=temp.x && endLP.x>=temp.x && startLP.y<=temp.y && endLP.y>=temp.y) && ((startLP.y-temp.y==0 && temp.x-startLP.x==0) || ((temp.r-startLP.r)/(temp.c-startLP.c))==1))
                    {
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y > endLP.y && startLP.x > endLP.x && ((startLP.r-endLP.r)/(startLP.c-endLP.c))==1)//checking right to left diagonal (down to up)
            {
                for(var z = letterPoints.length-1; z>=0; z--)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((startLP.x>=temp.x && endLP.x<=temp.x && startLP.y>=temp.y && endLP.y<=temp.y) && ((startLP.y-temp.y==0 && startLP.x-temp.x==0) || ((startLP.r-temp.r)/(startLP.c-temp.c))==1))
                    {   
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(startLP.y < endLP.y && startLP.x > endLP.x && ((endLP.r-startLP.r)/(startLP.c-endLP.c))==1)//checking right diagonal (top to bottom)
            {
                for(var z = 0; z<letterPoints.length; z++)
                {
                    var temp = letterPoints[z];
                    if((startLP.x>=temp.x && endLP.x<=temp.x && startLP.y<=temp.y && endLP.y>=temp.y) && ((startLP.y-temp.y==0 && startLP.x-temp.x==0) || ((temp.r-startLP.r)/(startLP.c-temp.c))==1))
                    {   
                        result += temp.letter;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(result != "")
                return result;
            return null;
        }
        //letter class
        function Letter(letter,x,y){
            //The letter variable is mainly used for getting the highlighted word
            this.letter = letter.charAt(0);

            //the x and y coordinate variables are used for drawing the highlighting line and getting the letter variable at certain coordinates
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            //the r and c variables are used to keep track of which rows and columns the letters are on.  This is very helpful for drawing the highlighting line on a diagonal
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="wordsCanvas" style="border: none;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using only offsetLeft and offsetTop inside setLine, you do not take into account the scrolling.

Killer weapon here is getBoundingClientRect, that will give you relative position of the canvas taking every aspect into account :

```
    function setLine(action, e){//sets the coordinates for the lines to be drawn
      var bRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

      var relX = e.clientX  - bRect.left ;
      var relY = e.clientY - bRect.top;

      if(action == "press")
        {
            startLP = findNearestLP(relX, relY);//gets nearest coordenate to a click and returns a letter object with that info
            if(startLP != null)
            {
                draw = true;
            }
        }
        if(action == "drag")
        {
            //updates the last coordinates that the dragged mouse is on and draws a line to that point from the start
            if(draw)
            {
                context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
                background();
                endLP = findNearestLP(relX, relY);

                context.fillStyle = "red";
                drawLine(startLP, endLP);
            }
        }
        if(action == "release"  || (action == "out" && draw))
        {
            draw = false;
            /*If a correct word is highlighted, store the start and end coordinates
            else clear*/
            endLP = findNearestLP(relX, relY);
            //Get the letters that are highlighted by the line
            if(endLP != null)
            {
                var word = getWord();//returns the word that was made from the start to end point by adding the characters that were highlighted
                if(word != null && matchWords(word)/*This string will be replaced by a word from the list of word search targets*/)
                {
                    lines[lines.length] = [startLP,endLP];
                }
            }
            context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);//clears the board of any drawn lines
            background();//if the line highlighted a word from the list, this method should redraw that line

            if(words.length == 0)
                alert("Congratulations! You win!");

        }
    }
```